# Windows Dualboot Bootloader Problem

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, bootloader

Being new to Ubuntu, for the past two days I am having trouble getting my Ubuntu and Windows dualboot to work together. The setup is as follows:
[Partition Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQbre.jpg)

- /dev/sda2 is where I want Ubuntu to be installed
- /dev/sda3 is the windows C: partition
- /dev/sda4 is a extended partition with windows D: (and hopefully later on the ubuntu swap partition)

At first I wanted to keep the windows bootloader instead of grub2. After messing around and figuring stuff out I installed grub on /dev/sda2 and added a entry to the windows bootloader with EasyBCD. However whenever I tried starting into Ubuntu I just got presented with a grub terminal (not grub rescue) and when using the ls command I got presented with the content of my C: drive.

After a lot of messing around I gave up and decided to let grub2 be my bootloader. I reinstalled Ubuntu again and everything seemed to be worked correctly on the first start. Grub booted up nicely and everything worked. Upon restarting my pc however it kept rebooting after the BIOS screen, so the bootloader was probably damaged again. I tried reinstalling Ubuntu again and once again it worked on the first boot but the ones after that the same thing happened.

I entered a liveCD and used bootrepair but I kept the same issue. I now have no idea how to procceed and I was hoping someone here might have any idea or suggestion on how to fix this.

Some final info: I do not know if this matters or not but my computer is said to RAID with a 24 GB cache SSD for windows.

Bonus question: I also have no idea why there is 4 Mib of unallocated space at the end of my drive, but as long as I can get the issue fixed I will be super happy and grateful.

Comment: May be best to see details: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info
 Is this an UltraBook with a small SSD for the hibernation files of Windows, often Intel SRT?

Answer (score 0):

> I also have no idea why there is 4 Mib of unallocated space at the end
>   of my drive
>   That is OEM partition and you just can't do anything. Stop worrying about that.

Please read the [installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) and how to [make partitions](http://www.howtogeek.com/214571/how-to-dual-boot-linux-on-your-pc/) before going any further.

Based on the current disk partitions you have - you can only install Ubuntu Linux on /dev/sda2(ext4-around 117GB). Let Ubuntu installer create a root (mounted a /), swap and /boot(if needed by grub2) on it's own when you are installing Linux.